# log4J Not Finding Properties file Used by JAR

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have a JAR that is run from the command prompt in Windows with the following parameter for log4J:

`-Dlog4.properties.file=C:/[folderName]/apps/[appName]/config/log4j.properties`

Even though the *log4j.properties* file is indeed in the path above, log4j fails to find it and thus fails to configure properly, and running the command with the parameter `-Dlog4j.debug` doesn't give me much more information:

`log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$Ap
pClassLoader@92e78c.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@92e78c
class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using     ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context     classloader sun.misc.Laun
cher$AppClassLoader@92e78c.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@
92e78c class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using     ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger     (com.xxx.yyy.appName.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`

I feel like I'm missing somrthing fundamental, so I'm open to ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though my problem was due to a Java version mismatch. The application in question currently only runs on 1.5, and I built the JAR accordingly. But one of its dependencies (i.e., another JAR) was built with 1.6. Rebuilt this other JAR with 1.5 and the problem went away...

Answer (score 1):

Try this parameter:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/[folderName]/apps/[appName]/config/log4j.properties
```

Comment: Both your suggestion and the one below don't seem to make a difference. I'll edit my question to include the messages I got when I ran log4J in debug mode, in case that helps...

Comment: Are you putting the system property before -jar flag to run your app?

Answer (score 0):

From the [short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
try using `file:` as a prefix on the path, only if your properties are not on the classpath. The property is also called `log4j.configuration` therefore your JVM argument should have following form:
`-Dlog4.configuration=file:/c:/[...]/log4j.properties`

Comment: I have eddited the answer - please try now.